# Save data from loop each determinate time

Tags: procedural-programming, save

I have a `Do` loop then I want to `Save` data from this loop each x number of iterations. My `Do` is some like:

```
     Estra = {}; it= 30
     Do[initial = 0; Estra = Append[Estra, initial]; 
           Do[op = 1 + i; Estra = Append[Estra, op], it], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Then I want to `Save` each number of iterations, for example each that `it = 10; it= 20; it=30`. I put that:

```
      Estra = {}; it= 30
         Do[initial = 0; Estra = Append[Estra, initial]; 
           Do[op = 1 + i; Estra = Append[Estra, op]; If[it = 10; it= 
                   20; it=30, Save["data.dat", Estra]], it], {i, 1, 3}]
```

But this save me all `Estra` each time and I want a continue list without repetitions. I mean:

The out of this loop is:

```
 Estra = {0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
       2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
       3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,4,4,
        4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
```

I want to `Save` this `0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2` and the this `0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3` and so on, and finaly have a file `.dat`:

```
  Estra = {0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
       2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
       3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,4,4,
        4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
```

Comment: May you provide some code for what you are attempting. Looping constructs are rarely used and there may be a better approach to achieve your aim.  Some code would help.

Comment: add  counter inside the do loop and  put it back  to zero when it reach the value you want?

Answer (score 1):

> Do loop then I want to Save data from this loop each x number of
>   iterations

One way might be

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
fd = OpenWrite["foo.txt"];

xNumberOfIterations = 3;
Do[
  m = RandomReal[];
  If[Mod[n, xNumberOfIterations] == 0,
   Write[fd, m]
   ]
  ,
  {n, 1, 10}
  ];
Close[fd]
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear how you want to save the data, but perhaps you could adapt something like this

```
n=1;
saved=Reap[
Do[y=RandomInteger[{1,10}];
  n=n+1;
  Print["Inside the loop we have ",{n,y}];
  If[n==4,Sow[{n,y}];n=1]
  ,{12}]
][[2,1]];
Print["And the saved results are ", saved]
```

That uses n to keep track of how often and when you want to save a snapshot, but prints every pass through the loop just so you can see what it is doing, and then when time comes to save the snapshot sends a copy using `Sow` which will be available using the `Reap` after the loop is finished. Try running that, look at what is printed and then look at the output from the final print to see that it shows your saved copies. You could change the `If` to have it save on any other condition that you need instead of what I used in this example.